# Java - Calendar / Date difference - Find difference down to seconds

Tags: java, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar, java.util.date

Trying to make a little Countdown program in Java.

I am working on the finding the difference between the dates part of the app, and for some reason I am only getting the days.

I want the days, hours, minutes, and seconds.  I am not sure why my calculation is just being rounded to an even integer... 163 in this example, and not 163.xx?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class CalcData {

    Calendar cal1;
    Date today;

    public CalcData() {

        cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
        today = new GregorianCalendar().getTime();

    }

    public String calcDiff() {

        cal1.set(2013, 6, 27, 7, 15, 0);
        double theDays = calcDays(cal1.getTime(), today);
        return "" + theDays;

    }

    public double calcDays(Date d1, Date d2) {

        double theCalcDays = (double) ((d1.getTime() - d2.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return theCalcDays;

    }
}
```

When I run this, as I said, I get the result: 163.0

I would think, if it is using milliseconds, that it would be some sort of decimal.  I am sure it is something simple that I am missing, but just can't find it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dividing an integer by another integer.  You need to cast those to doubles before you do the division.  Like this

```
double theCalcDays = ((double) (d1.getTime() - d2.getTime())) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

Comment: Sure enough! Thanks so much man.. Glad it was a simple mistake.

Comment: This will not work, if both dates are from different daylight time saving zones. In such case, time difference will be X days-1 and 23 hours :)

Comment: Indeed, in places that have daylight saving time, there is one day a year that is 23 hours long, and one day that is 25 hours long.  However, inside the date object is a value in UTC.  UTC has ONLY 24 hour days, and so it works.  You always have this problem when you consider time zones: a two hour phone conference might start and end in the same day in one time zone, and it might start and end in different days in a different time zone. They disagree on the number of days!  That has nothing to do with the duration, but instead the interpretation of the time according to that time zone.

Comment: You are correct, you CAN interpret difference of 23,9 days as 24 and the job would be done, hovewer, result itself is not correct, especially if you cast result to `int`

Comment: Actually, he is not looking for an int.  He is looking for a decimal with day and fractions of a day.  --------   The concept of time zone, 25 hours days, and daylight simply make no sense if the original question is to come up with a decimal that represents days and fractions of days.  I know you down-voted this answer because you know some things about dates, but if you visit the original question you will find there is no other reasonable interpretation.